# Запись/Чтение ключа/значения из файла PHP

Tags: php, кэширование, config

Здравствуйте. Есть некий php скрипт, который парсит сайты. Для работы скрипта ему нужна мини файловая key/value ДБ. То есть что-то типа того:
blablabla.txt/ini/php/ещечтото:

```
blallallallal:blalallalallalal2222
kkkkkkkk:kdadlask22
lll32139:dkllkalkdla
cache: ldkalkdlkd<br />tle;lt;<br />kldkasldkiuqiw41<br />и тыры пыры
```

Идей нету. Думаю, что ini не подойдет, ибо там будут очень-очень длинные строчки... а даже если он, то я понятия не имею, как это реализовать. В просторах интернета не нашел. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: С каких пор ini файл стал "мини файловая key/value ДБ" ? А не файловая БД это какая? Что конкретно вы не можете реализовать? У скрипта, который вы скачали есть описание по использованию.

Comment: Чем Вас json не устраивает?

Comment: А может и BerkeleyDB. Или даже Redis, или вообще sqlite... Вариантов - вагон, хоть какие-то критерии кроме "файловая" и "ключ-значение" ещё есть?

Comment: ArchDemon, Почему "скачал"? Скрипт сделал я, но я сам программист на java, просто знакомые попросили.. понятия не имею, какие у вас тут методы.

naym, Да пожалуйста, только, опять-же, я понятия не имею как его в php воткнуть.

klopp, Мне не нужна огромная БД на 100+ полей, а всего лишь 5-10 полей и не более. Никакие БД использовать не хочу для таких целей.

Ребят, вы наверное не поняли - в этом файле будет хранится временная информация, и время от времени менятся (примерно раз в 5 минут).. Мне не нужна БД для юзеров или чего-то подобного, просто временные файлы.

Comment: Берёшь данные, складываешь в массив, массив кодируешь в json, записываешь json в файл. Потом соответственно читаешь файл, разджейсониваешь, получаешь данные, обрабатываешь, заджейсониваешь, записываешь в файл.

Comment: @MrClon Спасибо вам. JSON меня абсолютно полностью устраивает, спасибо! =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По поводу json-а - это делается примерно так:

```
$fileData = file_get_contents($pathToFile);
$decoded = $fileData ? json_decode($fileData, true) : [];
if(!empty($decoded['somekey']) && $decoded['somekey'] == 'blablabla') {
  $decoded['anotherkey'] = 'qwerty';
}
file_put_contents($pathToFile, json_encode($decoded));
```

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php
http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php
http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: Спасибо и вам =)